# Many-to-Many Relationships in EF7 - Select query for a list including related data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am building a blog with the following Many-to-Many relationship on the content -> category tables. I have used the following code to generate the tables in EF7:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Categorization> Categorization { get; set; }
}

public class Categorization
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Excerpt { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Categorization> Categorization { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I attempt to load a list of categories, including the content associated with an EF7 query as follows, I get an error.

```
categories = await _db.Categories
                      .Include(c => c.Categorization)
                      .ThenInclude(c => c.Content)
                      .OrderByDescending(c => c.Categorization.Count)
                      .ToListAsync();
```

This is the error page that I get when this is called.

> A database operation failed while processing the request.
>
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.  AggregateException:
>   One or more errors occurred.  AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred.  AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
>   SqlException: Invalid column name 'Id'.  There are pending model
>   changes for ApplicationDbContext Scaffold a new migration for these
>   changes and apply them to the database from the command line:
>
> ```
> dnx ef migrations add [migration name] 
> dnx ef database update
> ```

Interesting note: When i remove the line

```
 .Include(c => c.Categorization).ThenInclude(c => c.Content)
```

It will sometimes work correctly, as in load the categorization, however this does not ALWAYS happen, sometimes the categorization doesn't load and I only have null references for Categorization in each Category class in the generated enumerable.

Comment: Using Include is normally a bad adiea, as the performance impact is quite heavy. if you have 10 Categories and 10 Categorization and 10 Content, you will retrieve 1000 (10*10*10) rows from the database. When getting them in 3 separate calls, you will only retrieve 30 (10+10+10) rows.

Comment: Sure, i understand the overhead of include, I am just using it to figure out the issue with the relationship. I am only using this to get a list of all the categories, and an associated count of the content in each category. Is there a clean way for doing this, perhaps a computed column for the count?

Comment: Assuming [Categorization.ContentId, Categorization.CategoryId] is unique  `await _db.Categories.Select(c => new {c.Id, ContentCount = c.Categorization.Count()}.ToDictionaryAsync(c => c.Id, c => c.ContentCount).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Fantastic! You inspired me to my final solution. I created a new POCO class to contain the count and the category, then simply ran a select to polulate my list. as follow: categories = await _db.Categories.Select(c => new CategoryApi { Category = c, Count = c.Categorization.Count }).ToListAsync()

Comment: Alas! Still receiving the SqlException: Invalid column name 'Id' when loading this line now. I have updated the model and the migrated the database several times. Also, the system continually detects that a change in the model has occurred yet, when a migrations add, it generates the exact same migration code as the previous migration, then still thinks there is a change. Odd!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all. SqlException: Invalid column name 'Id'

Your database is different than the models on your project. If you have database migration enabled then run the commands

```
dnx ef migrations add [migration name] 
dnx ef database update
```

If you don't want to use database migration, you have to update the models on your database to match your models.

Comment: I am using migrations, and the database is up to date with the migrations in my code, there seems to be something wrong with the model, as it continuously thinks there is pending change on the model, that doesn't exist in the migrations. I have ran the migration commants repeatedly, it simply generates the exact same migration code, and applies the same changes over and over, still thinking there is a change im my model afterwards.